# Measure constructed from the Lebesgue integral and a nonnegative function.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ be Lebesgue measurable. Is it true in general that the function:

$$\mu(E):=\int_E f$$

is a measure? The right hand side is the Lebesgue integral. I am having trouble proving the property of countable disjoint union. Suppose that $E_n$ ($n\geq1$) are disjoint sets, then:

$$\int_{\bigcup_{n\geq 1}E_n}f\quad\mathop{=}^{?}\quad\sum_{n\geq1}\int_{E_n}f$$

I know this equality is true for finite disjoint unions (using the linearity of the integral and the fact that $\chi_{\sum E_n}=\sum\chi_{E_n}$), but is it also true for countably infinite disjoint unions? (the linearity would fail in this case!).

Comment: Hint: When you want to pass limits inside an integral what do you usually do?

Comment: **Hint**: Use indicator functions and then justify the interchange of the integral and an appropriate sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, then yes, $\mu$ is an [absolutely continuous measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_measures) with respect to Lebesgue measure.

[Monotone Convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) of the indicator functions gives you the property of countable disjoint unions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see it now!

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you should look up:

- Radon--Nikodym derivative.  If $\nu(A) = \int_A f \; d\mu$ then $f = d\nu/d\mu$ is the Radon--Nikodym derivative of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$.  The Radon--Nikodym theorem says that under certain assumptions (including "absolute continuity" of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$), a Radon--Nikodym derivative exists.
- Density function.  A Radon--Nikodym derivative is the same thing as a density function.  Different ways of looking at it, maybe?  Or maybe not.